# I pass Facebook different URLs on a website and they return the same data each time?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem with requesting data from Facebook. I have tried a few different ways to get the number of likes for an individual page on a website that I manage, but each time I send a specific URL I get the same information back. The share and like and comment totals are the same for each URL that I pass to Facebook.

So for instance I send: 
http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=http://thiswebsite.com/page21/

or

http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=http://thiswebsite.com/page49/

and I get the same information returned.

I have Open Graph tags on the site and I think they are implemented correctly but even when I pass URLs directly as show above I get the same results. Could the og tags I have on the site be effecting the results Facebook returns, even if I am manually passing them to Facebook?

Comment: try using graph api.
https://graph.facebook.com/__YOURPAGEID__
example:
https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola

Comment: This is informative, for your comment I am guessing that I am sending the PAGEID to Facebook, the same ID for every page. I'm not sure if I'm correct on this one but I will have a look into it.

Any information or resources you could point me to in relation this would be helpful, and thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have two options to take. One's overly complicated but once you have it working you'll never have to worry about it. The other takes some time but requires a lot less effort.

I'll start with the simple one. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer. Once you get there your uid should already be there just delete every thing after it including the **?** and paste in

```
 /accounts?fields=id,name,likes
```

You will have to make and access token to see the data. You need the manage_pages permission checked on the extend permissions tab.

Once you do that hit submit and you should see in the results all the pages you're admin on the UID of the page, name and number of likes.

The other way is to build an app that handles this for you. Which you will have to register with Facebook and get an app id from them. With that app you can build a program that gets the information for you using php and or java script

Here's a sample of some php you can use.

```
require "facebook.php";

$config = array(
  'appId' => 'app_id',
  'secret' => 'app_secret',
  'fileUpload' => false, // optional
  'allowSignedRequest' => false, // optional, but should be set to false for non-canvas apps
);

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$user_id = $facebook->getUser();

if($user_id) {

  // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
  // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
  try {

    $path = '/' .$pageId .'?fields=likes';
    $pageData = $facebook->api($path,'GET');

    $likes = $pageData['likes'];


  } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
    // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
    // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
    // just ask the user to login again here.

    error_log($e->getType());
    error_log($e->getMessage());
  }   
} else {

  // No user, print a link for the user to login
  $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();


}
```

If you choose the longer route let me know I have this whole thing already built.